# project on writing phone book file

Tags: c

```
 struct phone
 {
      char fname[20];
      char lname[20];
      char pnumber[20];
 };

int main()
{

 int x=0;
 int n;
 char s[100];

 FILE * f;

 f = fopen("phone book","r");

 if (f != NULL)
 {
     printf("file exist !\n");   
     while(!(feof(f)))
     {
           fscanf(f,"%s,%s,%s",s[x].fname,s[x].lname,s[x].pnumber);
           x++;
     }
 }

 printf("1-   add");
 printf("2-   query");
 scanf("%d",&n);

if(n==1)
    printf("%s",s[n].fname);

if(n==2)
    fclose(f);

}
```

I write this program and there is a problem in `fscanf`

the comment for the error

```
 'main':|
  request for member 'fname' in something not a structure or union|
  request for member 'lname' in something not a structure or union|
  request for member 'pnumber' in something not a structure or union|
  request for member 'fname' in something not a structure or union|
 : variable 's' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]|

 : control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
 ||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 2 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Comment: Format your code, it's unreadable. ----- "and there is a problem in fscanf" - yeah, `fscanf()` is itself the problem, don't use it. You can use `fgets()` to read lines from a file, then `strchr()`, `strstr()`, `strtok_r()` and `strtol()` to parse each line.

Comment: first, `char s[100];` --> `struct phone s[100];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the errors

```
request for member 'fname' in something not a structure or union|
request for member 'lname' in something not a structure or union|
request for member 'pnumber' in something not a structure or union|
request for member 'fname' in something not a structure or union|
: variable 's' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]|
```

Change

```
char s[100];  // is not a structure. You need to declare it as structure
```

to

```
struct phone s[100];
```

and for the error

```
control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
```

as return type of `main` is `int` ( a non-`void` function whose return type is other than `void`) you need to add a `return 0;` statement before the closing brace `}` of `main`.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is declared to be `char s[100];`, so `s[x]` is a `char` and not a `struct phone`. You need to declare `s` as `struct phone s[100];` and the first of your problems will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the compiler is right. You declare

```
char s[100];
```

and try to access its members like it would be a structure array. It is just a char array.

I think you wanted to do something like

```
struct phone s[100];
```

This will declare an array s of 100 struct phone's.

Also, note that while(!feof(f)) it's not recommended to use in this case: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)